# Android WebView change color with transparent (chroma key)

Tags: android, webview, chromakey

I need to change (better also color in area) any color on **WebView** with transparent. 
It must work like **AvoidXfermode** (I can't use it because of deprecated)

*Example:*
I have red background and some dive with black color, I need to change this black color with transparent color and make a "hole" in WebView. In this hole, I must see any View what located behind the WebView.

Please help anybody ...

Comment: can you show what you have tried please

Comment: What kind of info you need ?